# matrix with distinct bounded eigen values is bounded?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

I am looking from the numerical methods perspective. I have a mapping $G$ that maps points in the numerical iteration to the new level. I would like to show its stability. For that I need to show that $||G||$ is bounded in some matrix norm. I happen to prove that the eigen values of $G$ are distinct and bounded by 1. How I can infer the boundedness of the mapping from there?

What I got by now is that from the fact it has distinct eigen values, I can diagonalize, that is there exist matrix $A$, s.t. $$G=A\Lambda A^{-1}$$ from where I can take norms of left and right hand side to obtain $$||G||\leq ||A|||| A^{-1}||\max{|\lambda_i|}$$Now I use the fact that eigenvalues are bounded by 1 and end up with an estimate $$||G|| \leq ||A|||| A^{-1}||$$ But do I know that that matrix $A$ is s.t. $||A|||| A^{-1}||\leq K$? I don't know such a fact. Can I have such a bound? Any help is appreciated!

The norm I consider is $||\cdot||_2$ norm, that is the spectral norm.

EDIT: looks like, there is no such a fact to deduce that $cond(A)$ is bounded in $L_2$ norm. Then, one way is to try to write what the matrix $A$ looks like and attempt to show its norm, along with a norm of $A^{-1}$. But that looks almost impossible to do considering that matrix $G$ has eigen values that are solutions to a complicated polynomial that are hard to find... On the other hand, there should be a way to estimate that numerically. But I don't know how yet. Any suggestions how to estimate that numerically? As before, what I have is my matrix $G$, that's pretty much the only input to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the eigenvalues are bounded above by 1 and are distinct (implies diagonalizable), you can always use the relation between the frobenius norm of the matrix and its eigenvalues, i.e.
\begin{align}
||G||_F^2=\sum_{i=1}^{N}|\lambda_i(G)|^2\leq N
\end{align}

Comment: Huh?  What about e.g. $$\pmatrix{1 & k\cr 0 & 0\cr}$$
Or are you assuming $G$ is normal?  The square of the Frobenius norm is the sum of the squares of the singular values, not the eigenvalues.